# Is there a way to setup .net trust in Group policy?

Tags: windows, group-policy

We are using roaming profiles where our settings are stored on a mapped drive.  Is there a way for me to set .net to trust this user profile path in group policy?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Roaming profiles...*shudder*. Are you also doing housekeeping on user's folders? Or are you also employing folder redirection? This is a whole other question! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific Group Policy setting that allows you to manage .NET Trusts, however you can write startup scripts to use the caspol.exe utility to trust specific locations or Assemblies. Running .NET applications of file shares can cause some unusual and difficult to identify errors.

**Trust a folder**

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
caspol -quiet -m -ag 1.2 -url file://server/path/* FullTrust
```

**Trust a specific assembly**

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
CasPol -quiet -m -ag 1.2 -hash SHA1 -file \\server\path\asm.exe FullTrust
```

You will have to modify the path based upon the version of .NET you are using, and or adapt the above to VBScript or PowerShell depending on your environment and experience.